# use beanshell to execute a scripts from a specific folder (error no such file or directory)

Tags: beanshell

I added the library bsh to my android project (jar file), the I create a file executor.bsh under scripts(a folder that I have created under the project) 
I used the code below

```
private final Interpreter i= new Interpreter();
i.source("scripts/executor.bsh");
```

I got an error:

> No  such file or directory

Help !!

Answer (score 0):

`Interpreter.source(..)` looks for a *File*, where you have a *jar entry*. However, you can still use it with:

```
try (Reader script = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("scripts/executor.bsh")) {
    Interpreter in = new Interpreter(script, System.in, System.out, System.err, false);
    // your script was already loaded
    // do something with Interpreter here.
}
```